# how to solve this error ? and use detachdb?

Tags: bitcoin-core, error

I got the following error

```
Error initializing database environment /home/rune/.bitcoin!  
To recover, BACKUP THAT DIRECTORY, then remove everything from it except for wallet.dat.
```

when I run bitcoin-qt..
I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this the first time (i.e. with an empty wallet) or were you using it and then now get this error?

Comment: Could you post the contents of `debug.log` when starting with the `-debug` command line option?

Answer (score 1):

back up all the files in .bitcoin.  then delete them all restart the wallet see if it errors.  If it does, re-download / re-install the client otherwise corupt configs.